# Creating Custom Domain to point Azure Storage Account - Static Website not working

Tags: azure, dns, azure-storage

I have created a static website in Azure, it gave me primary point url like `<mystorageaccount>.<somerandomcode>.web.core.windows.net` which is working fine from the browser.

Now, I followed below steps to use custom domain but no so successful.

1. created a `CNAME` with my DNS Service provider for `www.mydomain.com`
2. In Azure, storage accounts, mystorageaccount, Custom Domain, I entered `www.mydomain.com` but it throws error as

> Failed to update storage account 'mystorageaccount'. Error: The custom
>   domain name could not be verified. CNAME mapping from www.mydomain to
>   any of .blob.core.windows.net,..web.core.windows.net does not exist.

What I tried?
1. I tried with `mydomain.com` instead of `www.mydomain.com`, it accepted and showed me a message that it takes 30 min to propagate.

After about an hour, when I tried `www.mydomain.com` in the browser it throws me `The request URI is invalid with HttpStatusCode: 400.`
when I tried `mydomain.com`, server is unavailable.

2. in CMD, `ping mydomain.com` gives me some ip address so in DNS Settings I created A record with displayed IP address. After some time, `mydomain.com` is working as expected but `www.mydomain.com` still gives me `The request URI is invalid with HttpStatusCode: 400.`

Note: 
1. This IP address may not be static so creating A record with IP is not correct.
2. I tried to point to a `subdomain.mydomain.com` and at first attempt itself is working as expected but I want this to use to my `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`

What is the solution to work with www. and without www. to custom domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that [configuring a custom domain name for your Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name),

> The mapping does only work for **subdomains** (e.g. www.contoso.com). If
>   you want to have your web endpoint available on the **root domain** (e.g.
>   contoso.com), then you have to [use Azure CDN with custom domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn).

With Azure CDN, you can create `CNAME` or `A` record pointing to your Azure CDN endpoint. 
[Tutorial: Add a custom domain to your Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain)